# Measure CPU usage - Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++-2012

Does someone know how to measure the total CPU usage using Visual C++? 
I'm also needing a way to measure the memory usage.

**Update**
I just need something like this:

[image]

Please Help!

Thanks

Comment: For your specific process or for all processes (excluding idle)?

Comment: For all processes! Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the main thread with new info! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution using the Visual c++ performanceCounter Control.

Thanks!